# 'Game loop' in a none-game application?

Tags: loops, architecture, game-loop

In real-time games, there is always a game loop that runs every few milliseconds, updates the game with new data and repaints the *entire* screen.

Is this something that is seen in other types of applications, other than games? A *'constant-update-loop'*?

For example, imagine an application like MSPaint. The user can draw lines on the screen with the mouse. The line that is being drawn is displayed on the screen *as it is being drawn*.

Please imagine this line is actually made of a lot of smaller lines, each 2 pixels long. It would make sense to store each of these small lines in a `List`.

But as I said, the line that is being drawn (the large line, made out of lots of small lines) is displayed *as it is being drawn*. This means that a repaint of the screen would be necessary to display the new *small* line that was added the previous moment.

But - please correct me if I'm mistaken - it would be difficult to repaint *only* the specific part of the screen where the new small line was drawn. If so, a repaint of the *entire* screen would be necessary.

Thus it would make sense to use an 'update loop' to constantly repaint the **entire** screen, and constantly iterate over the list of lines and draw these lines over and over again - like in games.

Is this approach existent in non-game applications, and specifically in 'drawing' applications?

Thanks

Comment: The [reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) in asynchronous programming is essentially this loop.

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you do have a loop in all applications, and games.  How that is implemented depends on the system and desire of your application/game.  I will loosely base my response toward the Windows system, if only because you mention MS Paint

MS Paint will likely NOT contain a `List` of lines like you are mentioning, instead it will edit the bitmap image directly each frame, coloring the required pixels immediately and then drawing it.  In this situation drawing small portions of the image/application is as easy as telling "this part" of the image to draw itself "over there".  So as you move the pencil tool around the pixels turn black and get drawn.

MS Paint and most applications will use a primary loop that WAITS for the next event, meaning, it will allow the operating system (Windows) to not process anything until it has messages/events to process (such as: Mouse Move, Button Press, Redraw, etc).

For a game, it needs to be a little differently.  A game (typically) doesn't want the operating system to WAIT for the next message/event before processing continues.  Instead here you Poll the operating system to check if there are messages to be handled, and if so handle them, if not continue with the game creating a single frame (perform an Update and Render/Draw the scene.)

MS Paint doesn't need to keep updating and drawing when the user is not interacting, and this is preferred for applications because constantly updating/drawing uses a lot of system resources and if every application did this, you wouldn't have 30 things running at the same time like you probably do now.